# Negative lookahead regex to ignore list of words

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that will find any word that is followed by a space so long as that word is not `AND`, `OR`, `NOT`.

I've tried a negative lookahead after searching for similar problems, this is my current regex: `(?!AND|OR|NOT).*?\\s`

If I try this with "AND " I get a match on "ND". If I try with "OR " I get "R" and if I try with "NOT " I get "OT".

Can anyone help?

Comment: try this -- `(?!(AND|OR|NOT)).*\s`

Comment: Tried it there and it's still returning a match after the first character.

Comment: Can we see a string you're trying to match against?  What language is this?

Comment: I'm doing it in C#. I'm trying to parse queries that are sent into me. An example would be:

Name:The "Special" One AND XYZ

I have another query getting the name param. The XYZ is a value of a default field so it is sent without any delimiter, so I need to get it without getting the AND.

Not sure if that makes sense :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this pattern:

```
\\b(?!(?:AND|OR|NOT)\\b)[a-zA-Z]+\\s
```

I have added some word boundaries (\b) and used the character class `[a-zA-Z]` (you can replace it by [a-z] in a case insensitive context) to avoid the lazy quantifier.

or more performant (with case insensitive):

```
\\b(?>(?>[b-mp-z])|(?!(?>and|or|not)\\b)[aon])(?>[a-z]*)\\s
```

if you want to match:

- words between double-quotes without the double quotes or spaces:

`(?<=(\"?)\\b)(?!(?:AND|OR|NOT)\\b)[a-zA-Z]+(?=\\1(?:\\s|$))`

- words between double-quotes with the double quotes:

`(\"?)(?<=\\b)(?!(?:AND|OR|NOT)\\b)[a-zA-Z]+\\1(?=\\s|$)`

- words between parenthesis without parenthesis:

`(?<=(\\()\\b)(?!(?:AND|OR|NOT)\\b)[a-zA-Z]+(?=(?(1)\\)|(?:\\s|$)))`

- words between parenthesis and double-quotes without both:

`(?<=(\\()?(\"?)\\b)(?!(?:AND|OR|NOT)\\b)[a-zA-Z]+(?=(?(1)\\)|\\2(?:\\s|$)))`

- words that are not AND OR NOT without all that you want:

`\\b(?!(?:AND|OR|NOT)\\b)[a-zA-Z]+\\b`

Comment: This seems to work but I need it to match on " and ( also so for example

Name:The "Special" One AND "XYZ"

I changed the query to:

\\b(?!(?:AND|OR|NOT)\\b)[a-zA-Z\\\"]+\\s (Added in the \\\" at the end)

But it's only catching the last " in the words e.g.

Special" and XYZ".

Any suggestions?

Comment: @user2367873: you want to catch words between double quotes, but do you want to catch them with double-quotes or without?

Comment: I think I have it now, I added a \"?(? to catch any quotes or brackets at the start and changed the end part to catch anything.

Basically I'm trying to parse a large query with different possibilities. 

I have 2 regexs catching the first two possibilites and this one was to get anything left that wasn't one of them keywords. 

My query now: \"?(?\b(?!(?:AND|OR|NOT)\b).+?\\s

I think this will catch 0-1 " or ( at the start then the boundary to not give the AND|OR|NOT and then ungreedy anything until a space. Does that sound right?

Comment: @user2367873: I restate my question: do you want `"XYZ"` or `XYZ` in your results?

Comment: Sorry, I'd want "XYZ" basically want to catch anything that isn't AND, OR, NOT.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, I'm not 100% sure if I understood correctly, but could you try this and see if it's what you were looking for?

```
(?<=\bAND|\bOR|\bNOT)\s.*
```

This will match `XYZ` in your comment (though with the preceding white character). I tested it [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/eL1tH0) after adding a word in between.

**EDIT:** If there are no more characters to the right and you need the last three characters, you could use either:

```
\w+$
```

or:

```
[^\s]+$
```

Comment: So this will only match on words that follow AND OR NOT? Is that right, it's a positive lookbehind? 

It works I think in that case (where one of them words is first) but not if they're not.

I need it to match any word that is not them so it could be something like:

Name:Test IBM

I have another expression that is getting Name:Test. I need this one to get the IBM here. 

I have a few expressions, each getting separate cases, this one is to catch whatever's left but not those 3 keywords.

Comment: Wait, I just realised something... Are there more characters to the right? If not, you could use a simple `[^\s]+$` or `\w+$`.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately there could be :/ I'm starting to think there's an easier way to do this but @Casimir's answer from above got me a working version for now anyway.

Thanks for the help! I need to study my regex some more!

Comment: Okay. Good luck with the expressions! ^^ I'll try to learn some more too. I don't think I can come up with a regex like Casimir's yet xD